# Parsing "1/1/00" gives 1/1/0001 for the "mm/dd/yy" format in java. How to workaround?

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime

I have to parse date strings in formats that allow both "**yyyy**" and "**yy**" and java supports this case. I just have to add "20" or "19" to the year after calling to SimpleDateFormat.parse():

Initial           After              After adding
String          parse()           year prefix
"**1/1/01**" -> "**1/1/0001**" -> "1/1/**20**01"
"**1/1/96**" -> "**1/1/0096**" -> "1/1/**19**96".

This works fine for me, except for the problem of "2000": the string "1/1/00" gives "0001" year instead of "0000". How can I detect that the year is "00", not "01"? Thanks!

Comment: use `MM` for month. mm  is minute

Comment: Probably a good idea to use values other than 1 when testing this sort of thing. Ie 1/2/3 or 1/2/3000 etc. Makes errors/misconceptions more obvious.

Comment: Thank you, @Jens! The "mm" pattern is already used here.

Comment: @Poldie, thank you! The question is only about the ZERO YEAR thing. I think another misconceptions can be avoided by turning strict parcing on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To workaround the issue with the "00" year the strict parse mode can be used(`format.setLenient(false)`). In this case the parser won't allow to enter the "00" value and will result in an exception. So, for the "2000" year user will be forced to enter four digits and will not get the confusing "01" year. Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Nice find. If you want to correctly parse both 2-digit and 4-digit dates, you could then setLenient to false and first try parsing it as a 4-digit date, if that fails try the 2-digit-date.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created. For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be interpreted as May 4, 1964. During parsing, only strings consisting of exactly two digits, as defined by Character.isDigit(char), will be parsed into the default century. Any other numeric string, such as a one digit string, a three or more digit string, or a two digit string that isn't all digits (for example, "-1"), is interpreted literally. So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003" are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan 2, 3 AD. Likewise, "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.

Comment: Thank you, Neuhaus! The documentation says some generic, but nothing about the **ZERO** case.

Comment: If you create the SimpleDateFormat object in 2015, the year "00" should be interpreted as "2000" (not "2100")

Comment: this sample  
`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");  
 Date parsed = format.parse("11/11/00");   
 System.out.println(parsed);`  
  
gives a result as:  
  
`Sun Jan 11 00:11:00 BRT 1`  
which is "0001" year. The desired value is "0000". Thank you!

Comment: I'd say the mentioned behaviour only applies when you use "y" or "yy" but not "yyyy", as documented.

Comment: For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D. (straight from the Java 8 documentation)